# How do I define a type for a point in R^n for arbitrary n in Lean 4?

Tags: dependent-type, lean

I am new to Lean 4, and I was doing the exercises from [Functional Programming in Lean](https://leanprover.github.io/functional_programming_in_lean/getting-to-know/structures.html#exercises), in particular the one about defining a `length` function for a custom `Segment` type. Here is what I came up with, for reference:

```
structure Point where
  x : Float
  y : Float
deriving Repr

structure Segment where
  a : Point
  b : Point
deriving Repr

def length (s : Segment) : Float :=
  Float.sqrt (Float.pow dx 2 + Float.pow dy 2) where
    dx := s.b.x - s.a.x
    dy := s.b.y - s.a.y

def origin : Point := {x := 0, y := 0}
def p : Point := {x := 3, y := 5}

def s : Segment := Segment.mk origin p
#eval length s -- 5.830952
#eval Float.pow 5.830952 2
```

I would like to know how to idiomatically generalize this so `Point` is the type of any point in R^n for any n, and then write corresponding `Segment` and `length` definitions that make sense.

No doubt some analogue of this exists in `mathlib4`, but I'd like to write this basic version from scratch.

No doubt we need a type class here, perhaps something like

```
class Point (n : Nat) where
  components : Vector Float n
deriving Repr
```

but I'm not sure how to then use this to define the generalizations of `Segment` and `length`.

Comment: Usually, mathematicians in Lean define `α^n` for some type `α` as the type `Fin n -> α`. I don't know how easy that is to program with, however

Comment: "No doubt we need a type class here" No, a multi-dimensional point is as much a concrete value of a data structure as a two-dimensional point. There is no canonical point per `n`. So keep `structure` here (or make it a `def`/`abbrev` for `Vector`).

Comment: @SebastianUllrich Thanks very much for setting me straight! Yes `Vector Float` is really exactly what I needed. Turns out it was a silly question, I think. If you make your comment an answer, I'll mark it as accepted!

Comment: For anyone who might be confused by this, I had thought `Vector` was in `Init.Data` or something, but it is not. An implementation can be found in the Lean 4 source at `doc/examples/interp.lean`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No doubt we need a type class here

A multi-dimensional point is as much a concrete value of a data structure as a two-dimensional point. There is no canonical point per `n`. So keep `structure` here (or make it a `def`/`abbrev`).

```
abbrev Point (n : Nat) := Vector Float n  -- no need for `deriving` this way
```

Comment: Follow up: is there a nice way to get a "sized" version of `List` (like `Vector`) with all the methods that come with it?

Comment: Or, alternatively a hint on how to implement `def listToVector (xs : List α) : Vector α xs.length := sorry` and `def vectorToList (v : Vector α n) : List α := sorry`?

Comment: I'm not aware of any existing implementations of `Vector`. You can define it as a `Subtype` of `List`, then you can reuse the List functions and "only" need to prove the lengths are correct.