# How to define a polymorphic `Vector` type in Lean 4 as a `Subtype` of `List`?

Tags: dependent-type, lean, refinement-type

The `List` type in Lean 4's [prelude](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Init/Prelude.html) has a lot of nice goodies implemented, e.g. `List.map`, `List.join`, etc.

A classic example in dependently-typed languages is `Vector a n` where `a` is the type of the elements of the container, and `n` is the length. This allows you to do nice things like write a function `concat (u : Vector a m) (v : Vector a n) : Vector a (m + n)` whose type signature guarantees that the function returns a vector of the expected length.

Following a comment on a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72677090/12400477) I'd like to write a `Vector` type as a `Subtype` of `List`, as a first step towards getting these methods for a sized container. But I'm new to Lean, and I don't exactly understand how this works. `Subtype` takes a predicate `a -> Prop`, which appears to work a bit like a filter on the parent type, which in this case is `a := List`. But all lists are valid vectors, so it doesn't seem like this is much use. The predicate should always return `true`, no?

My question is:

> How can I use `Subtype` to get a subtype of `List` whose length is encoded in its type? And as a follow-up, how can I construct an element of this type from an existing `List`?

Answer (score 5):

You're right that all lists are valid vectors, but the predicate is exactly how to specify that the Vector has a certain number of elements.

```
def Vec (n : Nat) (a : Type) := { ls : List a // ls.length = n }

def myVec : Vec 3 Nat := ⟨[1, 2, 3], rfl⟩
```